# On and off animation with css - better on animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I am playing with on/off monitor effect from [here](http://codepen.io/lbebber/pen/XJRdrV), although my animation is not on switch, but on window scroll. I've set it up like this:

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var sctop = $(this).scrollTop();
    var element_top = $('.image_animation').offset().top;
    if (sctop > element_top) {
        $('.image_animation').addClass('off');
    } else {
        $('.image_animation').removeClass('off');
    }
});
```

```css
.before_content {
    height: 300px;
}
.after_content {
    height: 800px;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
}
.image_animation {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.image_animation img {
    z-index: 100;
}
.image_animation .background_image {
    width: 94%;
    height: 73%;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4%;
    left: 3%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover!important;
    background-size: cover!important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat!important;
    animation: imac 10s linear 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes turn-off {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1, 1.3) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -webkit-filter: brightness(1);
        filter: brightness(1);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    60% {
        transform: scale(1, 0.001) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -webkit-filter: brightness(10);
        filter: brightness(10);
    }
    100% {
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.05, 0.855, 0.06);
        transform: scale(0, 0.0001) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -webkit-filter: brightness(50);
        filter: brightness(50);
    }
}
.image_animation.off > .background_image {
    animation: turn-off 0.55s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.image_animation:before {
    content:"";
    width: 94%;
    height: 73%;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4%;
    left: 3%;
    background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="before_content"></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="image_animation">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/DL7AUy3.png" alt="">
        <div class="background_image" style="background:url(http://i.imgur.com/VRcQKtY.jpg);"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="after_content"></div>
```

The turn off animation works nice, but I have problem with turning on animation. I don't need anything fancy like in the original codepen, fade in would suffice. I tried adding class `on`, and then use that to initiate some kind of css change, but no luck. Also I tried with animation, but it's not working as well. Currently my image just appears, which is kinda lame.

Any idea how I could make this transition when scrolling back on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding in an extra style for an `.on` class to be added

```
.image_animation.on > .background_image {
    animation: turn-off 0.55s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) reverse;
    animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}
```

And altering your javascript to

```
 $(window).on('scroll', function () {
     var sctop = $(this).scrollTop();
     var $image_animation = $('.image_animation');
     var element_top = $image_animation.offset().top;
     if (sctop > element_top) {
         $image_animation.removeClass('on');
         $image_animation[0].offsetWidth = $image_animation[0].offsetWidth;
         $image_animation.addClass('off');
     } else {
         $image_animation.removeClass('off');
         $image_animation[0].offsetWidth = $image_animation[0].offsetWidth;
         $image_animation.addClass('on');
     }
 });
```

I also changed the `0%` keyframe to make the animation look better

```
0% {
    transform: scale(1, 1) translate3d(0, 0, 0); 
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1);
    filter: brightness(1);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Notice the scale is now (1, 1) so it looks better in reverse.

The `offsetWidth` lines are a little hack to refresh the animations so they don't have issues changing.

Check it out at

https://jsfiddle.net/hh7r4jes/1/

Comment: If I'm in a strict mode, I cannot use the `offsetWidth` hack, is there any way around it?

Comment: Have you tried commenting it out and seeing if it works without it in strict mode?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work that well, the image blinks on start, and stretches the image out of the monitor container.

Comment: Did you change the css like i told you? `transform: scale(1, 1) translate3d(0, 0, 0); ` is important to stop the image stretching out of the container

Comment: Yeap, no go. The problem is that it adds the `on` class when you start to scroll.